# How do I add custom CSS to individual pages?

Tags: theming, search, 7

Im trying to create pages with a search bar in a specific non block area in Drupal 7. If I edit using Live CSS (or another module), it edits all my pages, and offsets the content I created. I need a way to edit the CSS styles for each individual page; in that way, I can edit the search form area, and have also a way to add my own button images.

I can disable Drupal regions/blocks, but that doesn't really help. May someone name some modules that could help, or suggest me some code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well the absolute simplest way is to look at the body class using firebug or developer tools with chrome.

You will see something like this:

```
<body class="html not-front logged-in no-sidebars page-node page-node- page-node-19 node-type-log-node admin-menu">
```

Which as you can see even has the node id for the page. Then its just a simple case of using

```
.page-node-19 {
background: #000000;
}
```

Or whatever!

And, if you want to get super in detail with adding stuff to certain pages, themes, regions, dependencies on which users etc etc then look into the [context](http://drupal.org/project/context) module and all its related modules.

Answer (score 2):

The Context module, combined with the Panels module can be of great help.

You can hack also the master template a bit, inserting if/else statements, but hacking should be avoided as much as possible.

Comment: Context also places all of your tweaks in a single location. If you document the description well, editing later becomes easy.